# Assigning function to function pointer with template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

So I have these two functions:

```
bool intComp(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b;
}

bool stringComp(std::string a, std::string b)
{
    return strcmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str()) > 0;
}
```

And in my sort function I want to assign either the stringComp or intComp function:

```
template<typename T>
void sort(std::vector<T>& vector)
{
    bool (*compare)(T a, T b);

    if (typeid(T) == typeid(int))
    {
        compare = &intComp;
    }
    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::string))
    {
        compare = &stringComp;
    }
    ...
}
```

The assignment and sorting works fine when I remove the else if block with `compare = &stringComp`. But as soon as I try to assign functions with types other than `int` (for instance string) I get the following compiler error: `'=': cannot convert from 'bool (__cdecl *)(std::string,std::string)' to 'bool (__cdecl *)(T,T)'` What am I doing wrong? And why does the code work with int but not with other types? Do templates maybe work with integers under the hood similar to enums and that's why I can assign the intComp function without issues?

Comment: The problem is that your code tries to implement all possible template instantiations in your `if / else` ladder. You might rather try something like `std::enable_if<>`.

Comment: Are you using C++17 or later?  `if constexpr` could help you avoid runtime assignments that are not correct.  There is no value of `T` that would make both of your assignments correct at runtime, which is what you are attempting now.

Comment: Why not do what [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) does?  Look at (3) at the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that *all* branches of a normal `if` need to be valid at compile time, but only one of the branches in yours is.  If `T` is `int`, then `compare = &stringComp` is invalid.  If `T` is `std::string`, then `compare = &intComp` is invalid.

Instead, you need `if constexpr`, which was introduced in C++17 and does its comparison at compile time.  It discards branches that it doesn't take as long as it's dependent on a template parameter, so it doesn't matter if they don't make sense for that type.  For example:

```
template <typename T>
void sort(std::vector<T>& vector)
{
    bool (*compare)(T a, T b);

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        compare = &intComp;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
        compare = &stringComp;
    } else {
        // Error
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, thats it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 you can use constexpr if:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

bool intComp(int a, int b) { return a < b; }

bool stringComp(std::string a, std::string b) { return a < b; }

template<typename T>
void sort(std::vector<T>& vector)
{
    bool (*compare)(T a, T b);

    if constexpr (typeid(T) == typeid(int))
    {
        compare = &intComp;
    }
    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::string))
    {
        compare = &stringComp;
    }
    
}
```

Before, and I'd actually use it in C++17 and beyond, you can let overload resolution pick the right function:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

bool Comp(int a, int b) { return a < b; }

bool Comp(std::string a, std::string b) { return a < b; }

template<typename T>
void sort(std::vector<T>& vector)
{
    if (vector.size() > 1) {
        std::cout << Comp(vector[0],vector[1]);
    }        
}
```

Comment: I did not know that overloads work that smooth with templates. Will definitely consider this in the future. Thanks for letting me know.